# Операции над примитивами

Tags: java, примитивы

Будет ли иметь смысл выражение:
double d = 8 / 10;
Я имею в виду, будет ли получаться десятичное число 0.8
P.s: просто читал, что при делении целых чисел остаток отбрасывается, однако конкретно объяснено не было.

Comment: В чём проблема проверить это самому?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут дело в порядке выполнения операций. Сначала вы делите один int на другой, а только после этого присваиваете значение переменной с типом double, что вызовет приведение типа, но приведение именно для результата деления int на int.
И да, лучше проверять такие гипотезы на практике, а вот если непонятен результат проверки - уже задавать вопрос по теме которая непонятна.

Comment: Спасибо. Просто в данный момент не имею возможности работать с компьютером